# Como adicionar grupos e items em um ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Vou refazer a pergunta e tentar me expressar melhor...

Estou utilizando o `BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView´, não é o tradicional ListView da Microsoft - Visual Studio ele é bem mais completo [Para saber mais sobre o objeto click aqui](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)

A minha dificuldade está após o "if" onde eu verifico se o grupo já foi criado...

Não consigo adicionar o grupo, não aparece no ObjectListView.

Lembrando que qualquer ajuda é bem vinda...

Desde já agradeço.

Segue abaixo parte do código:

```
private void preencherListaProduto(ProdutosColecao produtosColecao){

// limpar os itens do ObjectListView

this.objltwProduto.Items.Clear();

// pegar cada produto
foreach (Produtos produtos in produtosColecao)
{
    // verificar se ja foi criado um grupo para a categoria em evidência
    if (this.objltwProduto.Groups[produtos.Categoria.descricao] == null)
         // se não... cria grupo ---- Erro na linha abaixo
        this.objltwProduto.Groups.Add(produtos.Categoria.descricao, produtos.Categoria.descricao);

        // abaixo, adicinar o item atual no grupo....                             

     }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se há erro nos tipos:
o parâmetro recebe o tipo *ProdutosColecao*, enquanto o foreach está passando por *Produtos*.

Caso os tipos estejam corretos, poderia tentar usar Contains() para verificar se o item existe na lista.

```
if (this.objltwProduto.Groups.Contains(produto))
  this.objltwProduto.Groups.Add(produto);
```